# BCP divides content in Excel in two columns because of semicolon

Tags: sql-server, excel, bcp

I am trying to export table content from SQL-Server to csv file. I am using BCP utility and "|" as delimiter.
However, the content of one column is divided in two columns in Excel, because of semicolon (ABC;D)

A      |       B

ABC    |D

Wanted:

A     |            B

ABCD

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `bcp` doesn't work with Excel files at all. CSV files aren't Excel files. Excel does **not** read CSV files when you double click on them,  it *imports* them using the current user's locale settings. If you want to specify different separators you'll have to go to the `Data` menu and import the files with your own settings.

Comment: Yes, but when I open csv file in Excel I except to have everything within one column "A".

Comment: If you want Excel to import a text file simply by double-clicking, ensure the column separator matches the target system's locale - `,` for America and China, `;` for Europe, Africa and Middle East. To handle fields with commas or semicolons, ensure they're quoted

Comment: `I except to have everything within one column "A".` how is Excel going to guess the delimiters you used? Besides, since you specified `|` as the delimiter, why do you expect the entire row to appear in a single column? Were you trying to "fix" Excel's behavior with formulas and VBA macros instead of eg importing the file or using PowerQuery ? Anyway, if you want to just double-click, make sure you use the expected delimiters

Comment: With ; as delimiter I get the expected behaviour in Excel. However, I was struggling with fields which contain semicolons. Where exactly they should be quoted?

Comment: If a pipe (`|`) has been properly defined when you opened the file in excel, then there would be no problem with semicolons (`;`) in the data; which means you haven't properly defined the delimiter when you opened the file in Excel.

Comment: @Larnu the problem is when I open csv in Excel, the rest of the content after ; is in column B. And I want to use Data->Text-to-Column option (which is only applicable on one column).

Comment: No, it isn't, @Dana, as i demonstrate in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with BCP or SQL Server, and all to do with how you didn't correctly define the file's properties when you tried to open it.

Open a new Worksgeet/Workbook in Excel and go to the Data tab in the Ribbon. Then click the "From Text" button, navigate to your file, select it and then press Import. A window like the below will then appear:

[image]

Most likely the File Origin with me ANSI or UTF-8 not MS-DOS. Also (at least for the example I have) I tick "My data has headers".

Click Next, and then you'll need define your delimited, that's a pipe (`|`), so select "Other" and then put a pipe in the text box. I've also select none for text qualifier, as I assume you have none, like so:

[image]

Notice that there are now 2 columns in the data in the image.

Then, finally, you can select and define some additional information. For example, for a phone number you'll want to define it as  text, and if you have dates, define those with the correct format. Anything else leave as "general".

Then select Finish, and the position you want the data, and done!